# Adding CSS and JavaScript links to elements.html

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm new to Polymer and one of the things I like is that I can declare global CSS styling and Javascript libraries in the `elements.html` file.  However, in the demos I have seen `elements.html` has been reserved exclusively for importing Polymer templates.

Is it bad style to overload elements.html with CSS and JS imports?

Comment: The reason why the `elements.html` exists is because it tidy things up and make it easier for the programmer to see what elements have been imported to the page. You could just make a new file called **my-imports** and import whatever you feel like importing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong about including `JS` and `CSS` files in the `elements.html`.

Think of `elements.html` as a non-ui web-component.

There is just one important thing to remember:
Polymer team has created a tool called `Vulcanize` which takes a file like `elements.html` which imports all the custom elements, to knit them together into a single file for reducing the number `http` requests the browser makes to gather the required resources. Adding `JS` and `CSS` files here will get this tool confused and generated rather odd results.

So this is exactly why you don't see official examples and tutorials include `JS` and `CSS` files in the `elements.html`.

More about `Vulcanize`:
https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/concatenating-web-components.html

Hope my writing is clear.

Comment: I  totally agree with Adi - just make sure your `elements.html` isn't a generated file. Editing a generated file is a bad idea. Adi pretty much said it all this one though :)

Comment: It sounds like we are basically waiting around for the tooling to catch up.

Comment: FWIW, I don't *think* adding css and js files to elements.html will break vulcanize. If I recall, I've added link tags to CSS files in my elements.html before and it all vulcanized fine.